# Lon Lat Yaw Pitch Roll conversion into VBS4 using the DIS protocol

Tags: 3d, euler-angles, dis

I have the lon, lat yaw pitch roll of an aircraft which i need to forward into VBS using DIS to display the object.

example data:
Lon: 2.0445459
Lat: 12.4195886
Yaw: 180 (degree)
Pitch: 0
Roll: 0

The input required using DIS Entity Orientation takes
Psi:
Theta:
Phi:

Could someone please help explain what conversions are taking place to get to the required input, if i read DIS out of VBS at this location i can see:
Psi: 0.0554486

Theta: 1.3575
Phi: -3.1214

I take it there are some rotations happening (from researching the mind field online) but i am new to 3d modelling and haven't worked with this before, so i dont understand the process of going from one set of data to the other.

Many Thanks

I havnt tried anything as i dont know where to start

Comment: Hi MC-Spark, I'd start by finding out how your rotations are defined for your input and your output eg. you might find a zero yaw value for one case means pointing north and in the other it could mean pointing south. I'd guess roll pitch and yaw are in body-fixed axes. Not sure what convention DIS uses (but it looks like it expects radians so you'll need to convert from degrees at a minimum).